# How to get rid of white border on export in Illustrator (2019)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When exporting my logos, I get an border bottom. How can I get rid of that?

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Using Illustrator CC
I tried what I found on google

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

1: there is some item in that place where border is. Maybe some little figure size of a pixel or something. It happens sometimes. So try to copy those 2 elements: cloud and text, and paste it in new document and then export it. 
2: in wxport options you have set some preferences for borders.

Answer (score 0):

The font/text was the problem. I transformed the text element into paths.